# Approach to solve a Coupled system of PDE [Heat transfer in cylindrical coordinates]

Tags: heat-equation, laplacian, cylindrical-coordinates, partial-differential-equations

I have the following two PDEs, which describe steady-state coupled heat transport between a externally heated axi-symmetric solid body (Eq. 1, $T(r,z)$) and a fluid (Eq. 2, $t(z)$) flowing inside it:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial^2 T}{\partial z^2}=0 \tag1
$$

$$
\frac{\partial t}{\partial z}+\alpha(t-T)=0 \tag2
$$
Eq. (1) is defined in the domain $r\in[r_1,r_2]$ where $r_1$ and $r_2$ describe the inner and outer radii of the cylinder and $z\in[0,L]$ where $L$ is the length of the cylinder. The boundary conditions for Eq. (1) are:
$$
\frac{\partial T(r,0)}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial T(r,L)}{\partial z}=0 \tag3
$$
$$
\frac{\partial T(r_2,z)}{\partial r}=\gamma \tag4
$$
$$
\frac{\partial T(r_1,z)}{\partial r}=\beta(T(r_1,z)-t) \tag5
$$
For Eq. (2) it is known that $t(z=0)=t_{in}$

$\alpha, \beta, \gamma, t_{in}$ are known constants. It seems the solid and fluid temperatures are coupled through the B.C. at $r=r_1$ (solid-fluid interface, Robin condition).

Any suggestion on how to approach this problem analytically is appreciated.

Comment: So eq. (2) should actually be an ODE of the form $\frac{dt}{dz} + \alpha(t-T(r_1,\,\cdot\,)) = 0$?

Comment: @Christoph Yes you are right, It can be expressed in an integral form and the boundary condition $(5) $can be expressed as (using $t(z=0)=t_{in}$) $$
\frac{\partial T}{\partial r} \vert_{r=r_1}=\beta\Bigg[T-\alpha e^{-\alpha z}\bigg(\int_0^z e^{\alpha s} T(r,s) \mathrm{d}s + \frac{t_{in}}{\alpha} \bigg)\Bigg]
$$ I could not proceed after this

Comment: You can get the solution $T(r,z)$ of (1), (3) by separation of variables. It should contain constants whose values must be determined from (4), (5).

Comment: @Christoph I did try to attempt the problem using separation of variables. The obstacle comes with the boundary condition at $r=r_1$ whose structure I mentioned in my previous comment. I will give it another go and post my attempt If i could proceed anywhere.